# Handle empty files in CsvHelper

Tags: csvhelper

We are using CsvReader to extract data from hundreds of CSV files. On occasion, we are fed an empty file. If I call `Read()` or `ReadHeader()` I end up with an exception. I think `ReadHeader()` should just return `false`, but I was wondering if I am missing something.

Is there a way to handle this more gracefully (i.e. without exceptions being thrown)?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is `No header record was found` as stated [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/572). Check the `Stream.Length` before processing the file, and if it's 0, don't process it.

Comment: Azure Data Lake does not allow the use of `Stream.Length`. It results in a `NotSupportedException`.But given that ReadHeader returns a boolean, it's strange that it just throws an exception instead of returning false.

Comment: That's unfortunate. What if the file contains only headers and newlines (my case)? `Read()` and even `ReadHeader()` throw even though the headers do exist